# Windows on SSD, Ubuntu on HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

In my system (MSI GS60) I have 2 SSD (on a Raid0) for Windows, and an HDD where I want to create a partition to install Ubuntu.

I have been reading about the optimizations you need to do to install Ubuntu on an SSD (such as the `noatime` attribute), but given that I am going to install Ubuntu on my **HDD**, I would like to know:

- Is it necessary for me to do the same SSD optimizations? (I will still mount the SSD Raid, formatted in NTFS, even though Ubuntu is not installed there)
- Is there any way I can use the Windows Boot Loader to detect the Ubuntu Partition?
- If I install Grub, where should I install it: HDD or SSD? If I install it on the SSD is there any SSD optimization I should take care of so that Grub reduces the number of writes?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think one can make the windows boot loader to detect Ubuntu. But the other way round it works

Comment: Is your system using UEFI or BIOS boot mode? Makes a differnce on how you install. And then is HDD, MBR or gpt partitioned?

Comment: The system is in UEFI mode. SSD and HDD are in GPT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "noatime" is an extx filesystem attribute, which may have an equivalent for ntfs, but will probably be called something different.  The purpose of the SSD optimizations is to reduce the number of writes, and you certainly don't want to force a write to update the time you read a file, so you would want that particular optimization if it exists for ntfs.  Apply only the optimization which make sense, i.e. system related ones probably don't apply, unless you want some performance improvement instead of a longevity improvement.

The Windows bootloader -- can't say.

Grub on the SSD does not write much, and will certainly improve boot speed.  That said, If you want to put grub on the HDD, you can leave the SSD untouched (assuming you can boot either).  Some people see that as a benefit -- remove the HDD and have a pure Windows system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will install Grub to the HDD as you said. I would appreciate if anyone could let us know if there is any equivalent of "noatime" for ntfs. If I find it, I'll post it here.

Comment: In case this helps anyone, I have found out that the noatime attribute also applies for NTFS.