# How to install Ubuntu on different partition from Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I'm want to install Ubuntu on my computer, but I have some doubts about the installation process.

So I have a 256 GB SSD and a 2 TB HDD. I currently use Windows 10 as my primary OS and it's installed on my SSD in partition C: (it's important to note that my SSD has 3 partitions: a system backup partition, EFI system partition and C: )

Now, I'm forced to install Ubuntu on my HDD (it only has one partition: E:) because my SSD is almost full. Nevertheless, I can create a new partition on my HDD for installing Ubuntu

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on my HDD, which is partitioned as NTFS, and dual boot when I turn on my PC? If so, what's the correct installation process in order to do so?

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and I would like to learn more

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows on SSD, Ubuntu on HDD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/718215/windows-on-ssd-ubuntu-on-hdd) and [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ubuntu on different partition than Windows

It's not possible to install two Operating Systems on one partition.  Either you replace it on the partition where you have a different OS by choosing that partition for your install, or you Create a new partition and install the different OS on the new partition.

You mentioned that you know how to create a partition.  So perform that step and install the different OS on the partition you create for it.

### The Installation

Installing Ubuntu is a very seamless operation.  Just boot to the install DVD or the USB installer.  You'll be prompted to either **Install Ubuntu** or **Try Ubuntu**.  Follow the prompts and it'll be installed on your system.

If you already have an Operating System, as in your case, when you run the installer the install options will include install

1. **Alongside the current installed OS**.  With this option the installer will bring up a slider and allow the user to determine how much space to leave for the current OS and allocate for Ubuntu.  With this option you don't have to create a partition.  The Installer will split the partition for you, having one for your current OS (Windows) and the other for Ubuntu.
2. **Use the whole Disk for Ubuntu**.  This option would clearly remove everything currently on the drive and replace it with **Ubuntu**.
3. **Do Something else**.  On this choice you will be given an option to select a partition where you want Ubuntu installed.  This would be the option you would choose for placing the OS on the new partition you mentioned in your Question that you know how to create.

### Note

The installer will clearly notify with a confirmation prompt before making any changes to your system.  It'll tell you which changes will be made.

The process is probably easier done than said.

### Official Install Steps with pictures:

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: The partitioning the user can do is in Windows therefore there's no point in actually creating a partition, better to shrink the one already there, leaving unallocated space. Then option 3 "Do something else".

Comment: The OP didn't mention how his drives are divided.  It may different for most manufacturers now, but through the years I see many occasions where Windows is installed on a partition, not necessarily the largest portion of the disk, and the drive also includes allocated space and a huge data partition, many times not used.  The OP indicated that he knows how to create a partition.  To me it's an indication he isn't totally clueless when it comes to using space on his drive, his question was how it works.  So he has the three options with details that he can consider.